# Qt QTableVew selecting multiple rows

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have hit a problem with QTableView (Qt version 5.12.10).  I have create a very basic table class which just has the the following code in the class constructor:

[image: Screen shot]

```
setModel(pModel); // pModel is of a class derived from QAbstractTableModel
setWindowTitle("The Title");
setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

When I click on the left most column (not the id column) where it says 2, it will select the whole of row 2.
When I **shift** click on row 3 it also selects the whole of row 3.
When I **shift** click on row 4 in the first name column (any column except the left most) it selects row 4 and deselects row 2.

According to the documentation tis could be expected behaviour, but if all clicks are performed in the Name column then row 2 is not deselected.

Further after doing the above clicking on row 8 and the left most column reselects row 1 where as row 8 anywhere else does not reselect row 1.

It appears that the left most column has a selection value that the rest of the table can't fully access.

**Questions**:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Have I misunderstood the documented behaviour?
3. Does anyone know if there is a way of making the two sides work in the same way?

**Code**:
main.cpp

```
#include <sstream>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include "cmodeldata.h"
#include "cqtableview.h"

/// Display the row from a QItemSelection
std::string dumpQItemSelection (const QItemSelection& selection)
{
    int lastRow = -1;
    std::stringstream output;
    output << "(";
    for (auto index : selection.indexes())
    {
        if (index.row() != lastRow)
        {
            lastRow = index.row();
            output << index.row() << ",";
        }
    }
    output << ")";
    return output.str();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CModelData m_model;
    CQTableView *m_table = new CQTableView (&m_model);
    m_table->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

cqtableview.h

```
#ifndef CQTABLEVIEW_H
#define CQTABLEVIEW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTableView>
#include "cmodeldata.h"

class CQTableView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CQTableView(CModelData* pModel = nullptr, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QTableView(parent)
    {
        setModel(pModel);
        setWindowTitle("The Title");
        setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
        setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
    }

public slots:
public:
};

#endif // CQTABLEVIEW_H
```

cmodeldata.h

```
#ifndef CMODELDATA_H
#define CMODELDATA_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QStringListModel>


class CModelData : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum class EColumns
    {   // The order of the columns
          eId = 0
        , eFirstName
        , eLastName
        , eEmail
        , ePhone
        , eColumnCount
    };
public:
    CModelData(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    /// Get the number of rows in the data source
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    /// Get the number of columns in the data source
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    /// Return a cell of data
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    /// Return a cell of data relevent to the header
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    /// Add a row of data
    bool addRow (const int i, const QString& fn, const QString& ln, const QString& e, const QString& pn);
private:
    struct DataRow
    {   // This is a row of data
        int     id;
        QString firstName;
        QString lastName;
        QString email;
        QString phone;
        DataRow (const int i = 0, const QString& fn = "", const QString& ln = "", const QString& e = "", const QString& pn = "")
            : id(i), firstName(fn), lastName(ln), email(e), phone(pn)
        {}
    };
    QVector<DataRow> m_rows;
};

#endif // CMODELDATA_H
```

cmodeldata.cpp

```
#include "cmodeldata.h"

CModelData::CModelData(QObject* pParent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(pParent)
{
    addRow(0, "Alan", "Alanson", "alan@email.com", "0111 111111");
    addRow(1, "Bob", "Brown", "bob@email.com", "0111 222222");
    addRow(2, "Charlie", "Carlson", "charlie@email.com", "0111 333333");
    addRow(3, "Dave", "Davis", "dave@email.com", "0111 444444");
    addRow(4, "Eric", "Ericson", "eric@email.com", "0111 555555");
    addRow(5, "Frank", "Fallows", "frank@email.com", "0111 666666");
    addRow(6, "Geoff", "Geofferson", "geoff@email.com", "0111 777777");
    addRow(7, "Hugo", "Hadron", "hugo@email.com", "0111 888888");
    addRow(8, "Ian", "Indigo", "ian@email.com", "0111 999999");
    addRow(9, "James", "Jamerson", "james@email.com", "0111 000000");
}

int CModelData::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
   return m_rows.count();
}

int CModelData::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return static_cast<int>(EColumns::eColumnCount);
}

QVariant CModelData::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        /// return QString("Row%1, Column%2").arg(index.row() + 1).arg(index.column() +1);
        for (auto& item : m_rows)
        {
            if (item.id == index.row())
            {
                switch (index.column())
                {
                case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eId):
                    return item.id;
                case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eFirstName):
                    return item.firstName;
                case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eLastName):
                    return item.lastName;
                case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eEmail):
                    return item.email;
                case static_cast<int>(EColumns::ePhone):
                    return item.phone;
                default:
                    return QVariant();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant CModelData::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
    {
        switch (section)
        {
        case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eId):
            return QString("Id");
        case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eFirstName):
            return QString("First Name");
        case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eLastName):
            return QString("Last Name");
        case static_cast<int>(EColumns::eEmail):
            return QString("Email");
        case static_cast<int>(EColumns::ePhone):
            return QString("Phone");
        }
    }
    // return QAbstractTableModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
    return QAbstractTableModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
}

bool CModelData::addRow (const int i, const QString& fn, const QString& ln, const QString& e, const QString& pn)
{
    m_rows.append(DataRow(i, fn, ln, e, pn));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, when holding 'Shift', continuous rows are selected.
By holding 'CTRL' however you should be able to select arbitrary rows.

Comment: Agreed, so in this example I should end up with rows 2 to 4 selected.  This happens if clicking on column 2 but not on the left most column.  I'm not sure if I have done something wrong or if there is a bug in the way the left column is handling the shift clicks.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on 2 and then shift clicking on '4'? What does that do?
Does it select all three rows? Of course, Qt just being a (very big and complex) framework, bugs can, of course, not be ruled out either.

Comment: What flags does your model return for the first column?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Clicking on 2 then shift clicking on 4 left column selects rows 2 to 4.  but then clicking on col 3 on any row below or above causes the problem.  There is a way to stop it happening, by shift clicking 4 times on the other columns, but thats not something we can ask users to do really.

Comment: @chehrlic - It is returning the default flags, I hadn't overridden that, so it seems to be returning 0xA1 for all cells (Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable)

Comment: Does it behave the same when using a e.g. QStringListModel? If so please provide a minimal, compilable example. Do you have a chance to test it with Qt5.15?

Comment: @chehrlic QStringListModel has the same effect.  Recreated the project under 5.15 and I still see the same issue.

Comment: When you click on a row, the current index is automatically set to the first column of this row. When you do an extended selection later on, the current index is used for the new selection. Therefore the behavior you see here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Qt, I've created a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-92561

Comment: I prefer your minimal example :)

Comment: Thanks very much for fixing it, but is the fix going to be available in QT5.12 (the LTS version)?

Comment: You should ask the Qt support for this.